# pass anonymous function as a parameter

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala. 
I import function from another JVM language and helper shows me this signature

[image]

It confuses me.
In the original language I designed that function to work like this

```
dsl {
   method { }
   header { }
}
```

But how it will look like in Scala?

In another language the `dsl` looks like this

```
class GRLMessageDSL : GRLMessage() {

    fun dsl(closure: GRLMessageDSL.() -> Unit) : GRLMessage {
        closure()
        return this
    }

    fun method(closure: GRLMessageDSL.() -> GRLProtocol.GRLMethod) : GRLMessage {
        methodType = closure()
        return this
    }

    fun headers(closure: GRLMessageDSL.() -> Unit) : GRLMessage {
        closure()
        return this
    }

    fun header(closure: GRLMessageDSL.() -> Pair<String, String>) : GRLMessage {
        headerMap += closure()
        return this
    }

    fun multipart(closure: GRLMessageDSL.() -> IGRLMultipart) : GRLMessage {
        multipartObject = closure()
        return this
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous function or lambda with one input parameter gets compiled to `Function1` interface in Scala thats why you see `Function1`

That means

```
val f = {x: Int => x * x } (this is just syntactic suger)
```

the above function is equivalent to (in fact compiled to)

```
new Function1[Int, Int] { def apply(x: Int) = x * x }
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val f = {x: Int => x * x }
f: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> new Function1[Int, Int] { def apply(x: Int) = x * x }
res1: Int => Int = <function1>
```

Comment: So how its usage will look like in Scala?

Comment: `val f = {x: Int => x * x } ` is syntactic suger for `new Function1[Int, Int] { def apply(x: Int) = x * x }` . So intellij shows the second one

Comment: hm so something like this? `val message = new GRLMessageDSl \n message.dsl ( message.headers ( message.header ()))?` Where I passed method invokations that return `GRLMessageDSL` instance

Comment: @user1432980 what is your `dsl` implementation

Comment: @user1432980 ... what is the input param of `dsl`